# Draw bigger Characters

Tags: java, graphics, jpanel

I am using `java.awt.Graphics2D` to draw some characters on my screen using the method `g2d.drawChars` but the size those characters are drawn is to small. Is there any way to make them appear bigger? Set a font size or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the font size using this:

```
 Font font = new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 18);  
 g2d.setFont(font);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Georgia", Font.BOLD, 18));
```